# How to change label "HD" in jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I am using below script for jwplayer, it is working fine for me, but there is an issue with label "HD", I want to change this label, How can i solve this ?

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("containerForShortVideo");
                    playerInstance.setup({
                    image: "' .Main_VideoUrl(ImagesUrl($VideoDetails[0])) /*S3_VIDEO_BUCKETABSOLUTE_PATH . $VideoDetails[0]['ImageName']*/ . '",    
                    //primary: "flash",
                    autostart: false,
                    //bufferLength : 0,
                    sources: [{
                              file: "' . S3_VIDEO_BUCKETABSOLUTE_PATH . $highResolutionURL . '",
                              label: "720p HD",
                              type: "mp4"
                            },{
                              file: "' . S3_VIDEO_BUCKETABSOLUTE_PATH . $VideoDetails[0]['VideoStreamURL'] . '",
                              label: "480p SD",
                              type: "mp4"
                            },
                            {
                              file: "' . S3_VIDEO_BUCKETABSOLUTE_PATH . $lowResolutionURL . '",
                              label: "180p",
                              "default": "true",
                              type: "mp4"
                            }
                    ],
                    advertising: {
                    client: "vast",
                    schedule: {
                    adbreak1: {
                        offset: "pre",
                        tag: "'.$adurl1.'", 
                    },
                    adbreak2: {
                        offset:"'.$adurmidtime.'",
                        tag: "'.$adurl2.'",
                    },
                    adbreak3: {
                        offset: "post",
                        tag: "'.$adurl3.'",
                    },
                      }
                  }
                    });
```

Here is the image 
[image]

Comment: Do you want to change text in the label or change the skin of jwplayer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("containerForShortVideo");
                playerInstance.setup({
                image: "' .Main_VideoUrl(ImagesUrl($VideoDetails[0])) /*S3_VIDEO_BUCKETABSOLUTE_PATH . $VideoDetails[0]['ImageName']*/ . '",    
                //primary: "flash",
                autostart: false,
                //bufferLength : 0,
                sources: [{
                          file: "' . S3_VIDEO_BUCKETABSOLUTE_PATH . $highResolutionURL . '",
                          label: "720p Your Name",
                          type: "mp4"
                        },{
                          file: "' . S3_VIDEO_BUCKETABSOLUTE_PATH . $VideoDetails[0]['VideoStreamURL'] . '",
                          label: "480p SD",
                          type: "mp4"
                        },
                        {
                          file: "' . S3_VIDEO_BUCKETABSOLUTE_PATH . $lowResolutionURL . '",
                          label: "180p",
                          "default": "true",
                          type: "mp4"
                        }
                ],
                advertising: {
                client: "vast",
                schedule: {
                adbreak1: {
                    offset: "pre",
                    tag: "'.$adurl1.'", 
                },
                adbreak2: {
                    offset:"'.$adurmidtime.'",
                    tag: "'.$adurl2.'",
                },
                adbreak3: {
                    offset: "post",
                    tag: "'.$adurl3.'",
                },
                  }
              }
                });
```

Just change the label.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. TO JUST CHANGE LABEL

> **Replace the label with your own label**

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("containerForShortVideo");
                        playerInstance.setup({
                        image: "' .Main_VideoUrl(ImagesUrl($VideoDetails[0])) /*S3_VIDEO_BUCKETABSOLUTE_PATH . $VideoDetails[0]['ImageName']*/ . '",    
                        //primary: "flash",
                        autostart: false,
                        //bufferLength : 0,
                        sources: [{
                                  file: "' . S3_VIDEO_BUCKETABSOLUTE_PATH . $highResolutionURL . '",
                                  label: "720p HD YOUR_LABLE", // change the label 
                                  type: "mp4"
                                },{
                                  file: "' . S3_VIDEO_BUCKETABSOLUTE_PATH . $VideoDetails[0]['VideoStreamURL'] . '",
                                  label: "480p SD YOUR_LABLE",
                                  type: "mp4"
                                },
                                {
                                  file: "' . S3_VIDEO_BUCKETABSOLUTE_PATH . $lowResolutionURL . '",
                                  label: "180p YOUR_LABLE",
                                  "default": "true",
                                  type: "mp4"
                                }
                        ],
                        advertising: {
                        client: "vast",
                        schedule: {
                        adbreak1: {
                            offset: "pre",
                            tag: "'.$adurl1.'", 
                        },
                        adbreak2: {
                            offset:"'.$adurmidtime.'",
                            tag: "'.$adurl2.'",
                        },
                        adbreak3: {
                            offset: "post",
                            tag: "'.$adurl3.'",
                        },
                          }
                      }
                        });
```

### 2. TO CHANGE JWPLAYER SKIN

> **Follow the url** - https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/css-skinning/skins_creating/#introduction